# Let $f(x)=\sin x\forall x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}],f(x)+f(\pi-x)=2\forall x\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)\forall x\in(\pi,2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=\sin x\forall x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}],f(x)+f(\pi-x)=2\forall x\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)\forall x\in(\pi,2\pi]$.If the area enclosed by $y=f(x)$ and $x$ axis is $a\pi+b$.Find $a^2+b^2$

---

Required area$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}f(x)+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}f(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}f(x)+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}f(x)$
I dont know what to put in second and third integral in place of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi f(x) \, dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi [2-f(\pi-x)] \, dx=\pi-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi f(\pi -x) \, dx\overbrace{=}^{\text{use } t=\pi-x}\pi-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(t) \, dt.$$
Similarly
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(x) \, dx=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(2\pi-x) \, dx\overbrace{=}^{\text{use } t=2\pi-x}\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(t) \, dt+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt$$
Now you add all the integrals to get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}f(x) \, dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x \, dx + \pi+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x \, dx + 2\pi-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(t) \, dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin x \, dx + 2\pi-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin t \, dt\\
& =2\pi.
\end{align*}
Assuming $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$, we can say $a=2$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in(\frac\pi2,\pi]$, $\pi-x$ is in $[0,\pi/2]$. Therefore $f(\pi-x)=\sin(\pi-x)$. Looking at the second expression, you can write $$f(x)=2-f(\pi-x)=2-\sin(\pi-x)$$ for the second interval. Repeat the procedure for the third interval. You will need to split that into $x\in(\pi,3\pi/2]$ and $x\in(3\pi/2,2\pi]$.

As for finding $a^2+b^2$, you need to have more constraints. Are they any real numbers or rational numbers. Say the integral is $\pi$. Then $a=1,b=0$ is one solution. But so is $a=0,b=\pi$. In one case you have $a^2+b^2=1$, in the other case $a^2+b^2=\pi^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think with shifting of graph.For  the case when $ f(x) + f(\pi -x) = 2$, $\pi -x $ lies between $ [\pi/2, \pi] $so it becomes sin ( $\pi-x$).